# Parameter error in the clustering process

Tags: python, cluster-analysis

I try to cluster the data set and get the label with python. But it turns wrong about the parameter.

About the data set "player_playoffs_career_data":

```
[[2.5600e+02 3.2000e+03 1.4650e+03 ... 3.2100e+02 2.2500e+02 3.0000e+00]
 [1.5600e+03 5.7446e+04 3.8387e+04 ... 9.3040e+03 6.7120e+03 1.8000e+01]
 [5.8600e+02 1.5633e+04 8.5530e+03 ... 1.1610e+03 1.0510e+03 1.3390e+03]
 ...
 [7.0000e+00 3.0000e+01 2.0000e+00 ... 0.0000e+00 0.0000e+00 0.0000e+00]
 [5.3000e+01 3.9800e+02 1.1800e+02 ... 3.6000e+01 2.0000e+01 0.0000e+00]
 [5.6000e+01 0.0000e+00 2.7300e+02 ... 1.0900e+02 7.7000e+01 0.0000e+00]]
```

I've search the Internet to find out the dtype of the parameter of function "AgglomerativeClustering.fit()" or "AgglomerativeClustering.fit_predict()". I don't know what's wrong with it.

About the code:

```
player_playoffs_career_data_label = AgglomerativeClustering.fit_predict(player_playoffs_career_data)
```

About the error:

```
fit_predict() missing 1 required positional argument: 'X'
```

So what's the problem?

Thank you for your answer and advice.

Comment: Should I change the data into another type?

Answer (score 0):

I guess I find out the problem is. I miss a "()" after "AgglomerativeClustering".
Thank you anyway.